# FSCalendar: Header View from scratch?

Tags: swift, fscalendar

> Any help would be greatly apreciated. For the past week I have been searching everything I can find to make a custom Header View for a calendar. Basic really just a very large Font with subtitle of year.
>
> **Calendar Config**

```
extension FSCalendar {
func customizeCalendar() {
    appearance.caseOptions = [.headerUsesUpperCase]
    appearance.headerDateFormat = "MMM"
    headerHeight = 0
    
    var header: FSCalendarHeaderView!
    header = CustomCalendarHeader()
    header.configureAppearance()
    
    
    appearance.headerTitleFont = UIFont.init(name: "SFProDisplay-Bold", size: 80)
    appearance.headerTitleColor = COLOR_BLACK

    appearance.headerTitleOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    appearance.headerMinimumDissolvedAlpha = 0.6
    
    appearance.todayColor = COLOR_PRIMARY
    appearance.todaySelectionColor = COLOR_BLACK
    
    appearance.titleFont = UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Bold", size: 11)
    appearance.titleSelectionColor = COLOR_BLACK
    
    appearance.weekdayFont = UIFont(name: "SFProText-Semibold", size: 11)
    appearance.weekdayTextColor = COLOR_GREY
    appearance.eventDefaultColor = COLOR_BLACK
    
    appearance.subtitleFont = UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Bold", size: 20)
   
    
    appearance.selectionColor = COLOR_BLACK
    
    
}
```

}

> **Attempt at a Header View**

```
class CustomCalendarHeader: FSCalendarHeaderView {

var label: CustomUILabel = {
    let label = CustomUILabel(title: "Header")
    label.font = UIFont.init(name: "SFProDisplay-Bold", size: 60)
    return label
}()
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to subclass a class that shouldn't be subclassed. Copy the code from `FSCalendarHeaderView` to make your own HeaderView. Then inside `FSCalendar.customizeCalendar()`, replace `var header: FSCalendarHeaderView!` with `var header: MyCustomHeader`. Inside your custom header, do all the setup you want, remove subviews you don't want etc, but be sure to keep all the variable names the same to avoid conflicts in the FSCalendar framework.

Comment: Ok so I attempted to go back and do it this way to be able to update the months with built in delegate methods. However I realize the pods are in Obj-C ? So how can I make a custom sub class ? Can you post an example please